# (Android) Unable to retrieve Firebase data with another application on the same Firebase Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 different applications which use one Firebase Realtime Database.
The first app to input some data to the database and other app that must be enable to read data on the database.

I'm using listview to retrieve the data on the 2nd application,
but somehow the data won't show up, the application can only show a blank screen.
I already test the code on the 1st app (the one that I use to write the data) and it works perfectly (it show all the data).

There is no error, but there's still nothing in the listview of the 2nd app.

**Here's the database**

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKsFj.png)

**Here's my code**

```
private ListView listViewDemografi;
private List<Demografi> demografiList;

DatabaseReference databaseDemografi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseDemografi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data");
    listViewDemografi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDemografi);
    demografiList = new ArrayList<Demografi>();

}
@Override
protected void onStart (){
    super.onStart();
    //attaching value event listener
    databaseDemografi.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous artist list
            demografiList.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting data
                Demografi demografi = postSnapshot.getValue(Demografi.class);
                //adding data to the list
                demografiList.add(demografi);
            }

            //creating adapter
            DemografiList artistAdapter = new DemografiList(MainActivity.this, demografiList);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewDemografi.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Demografi.java**

```
public class Demografi {
    String dataJk;
    String dataUsia;
    String dataEdu;
    String dataJob;
    String dataEmail;

    public Demografi(){

    }

    public Demografi(String dataJk, String dataUsia, String dataEdu, String dataJob, String dataEmail){
        this.dataJk = dataJk;
        this.dataUsia = dataUsia;
        this.dataEdu = dataEdu;
        this.dataJob = dataJob;
        this.dataEmail = dataEmail;
    }

    public String getDataJk() {
        return dataJk;
    }

    public String getDataUsia() {
        return dataUsia;
    }

    public String getDataEdu() {
        return dataEdu;
    }

    public String getDataJob() {
        return dataJob;
    }

    public String getDataEmail() {
        return dataEmail;
    }
}
```

**DemografiList.java**

```
private Activity context;
List<Demografi> demografi;

public DemografiList(Activity context, List<Demografi> demografi) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_demografi_list, demografi);
    this.context = context;
    this.demografi = demografi;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_demografi_list, null, true);

    TextView tvJk = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewJk);
    TextView tvUsia = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsia);
    TextView tvEmail = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    TextView tvEdu = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPend);
    TextView tvJob = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewJob);

    Demografi artist = demografi.get(position);

    tvJk.setText(artist.getDataJk());
    tvUsia.setText(artist.getDataUsia());
    tvEmail.setText(artist.getDataEmail());
    tvEdu.setText(artist.getDataEdu());
    tvJob.setText(artist.getDataJob());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

Comment: is the login different on both the apps, cause the isAuthenticated flag in the db might be causing this

Comment: there's still no login function in these apps, because i wanna test it first without any authentication.

Comment: but what about the database?

Comment: I just add the database data to the post, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to link both the applications to the same firebase projects;
Tools->Firebase->Connect to FireBase and now link it to the same project.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

i just made a new project and connect it to the firebase and it worked perfectly.
But I still dont know what is the problem with the 2nd application though.